# Wait inside loop bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, while-loop, wait

I have created a loop to read through a `.txt` and execute another shell using each line as input.

**PROBLEM:** I need the loop to execute the first two lines from the txt in parallel, wait for them to finish, then execute the next two lines in parallel.

**ATTEMPT AT SOLUTION:** I thought of adding in a wait command, just not sure how to structure so it waits for every two lines, as opposed to each churn of the loop.

My current loop:

```
cat input.txt | while read line; do
export step=${line//\"/}
export step=ExecuteModel_${step//,/_}
export pov=$line
$owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh" processCalcScriptOptions "$appName" "$pov" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$appLogFolder""/"$step"_ProcessID.log"

/app/dev2/batch/hpcm/shellexe/rate_tool2/model_automation/check_process_status.sh "$appLogFolder" "$step" > "$appLogFolder""/""$step""_Monitor.log"
```

Input txt:

```
SEQ010,FY15
SEQ010,FY16
SEQ020,FY15
SEQ020,FY16
SEQ030,FY15
SEQ030,FY16
SEQ030,FY15
SEQ030,FY16
SEQ040,FY15
SEQ040,FY16
SEQ050,FY15
SEQ050,FY16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you'd use `sem`, `xargs` or `parallel` to parallelize a loop, but all these tools optimize throughput by always having 2 (or N) jobs running in parallel, and starting new ones as old ones finish.

To instead run pairs of jobs and wait for both to finish before considering starting more, you can just run them in the background and keep a counter to `wait` every N iterations:

```
printf "%s\n" {1..10} | while IFS= read -r line
    do
       echo "Starting command"
       sleep 2 &

       if (( ++i % 2 == 0 ))
       then
         echo "Waiting..."
         wait
       fi
    done
```

Output:

```
Starting command
Starting command
Waiting...
Starting command
Starting command
Waiting...
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What do you mean?

Comment: Given the request `wait` is exactly correct here and `sleep` is incorrect.

Comment: The only thing to note here is that this will make it impossible (unless there's a trick I don't know) to get the exit statuses of the waited on commands.

Comment: @  Karoly Horvath I thought sleep isn't a response to any process, it just sleeps for however long you tell it...wait will actually wait for the process to finish

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for the help!! I tried your command and it did what expected, but when I modified my script it doesn't seem to be doing anything differently. The first two lines dont run in parallel and wait, they each are running to completion before kicking off the next. Have I modified incorrectly?

Comment: cat input.txt | while read line; do
export step=${line//\"/}
export step=ExecuteModel_${step//,/_}
export pov=$line
$owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh" processCalcScriptOptions "$appName" "$pov" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$appLogFolder""/"$step"_ProcessID.log"

/app/dev2/batch/hpcm/shellexe/rate_tool2/model_automation/check_process_status.sh "$appLogFolder" "$step" > "$appLogFolder""/""$step""_Monitor.log"  sleep 2 &

       if (( ++i % 2 == 0 ))
       then
         echo "Waiting..."
         wait
       fi
    done

Comment: @PrestonAlexander In my example, `sleep 2` is the command to run in the background for illustration purposes. You should run your own command in the background with `&`, and not have `sleep 2` anywhere.

Comment: @thatotherguy hope you're not tired of helping yet....if I add & at the end of my commands it just creates all the log files, and seems to execute all simultaneously...as if its not actually kicking off the execution and waiting for completion. I am thinking maybe because I am outputing to the log files, so the ampersand isnt being read properly. I tried it after the .sh and before the >log as well, but didnt work. $owsdirectory"/hpm_ws_client.sh" processCalcScriptOptions "$appName" "$pov" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$appLogFolder""/"$step"_ProcessID.log"  &

Comment: @thatotherguy I actually think I may have just been putting it after the wrong line....since monitor.log is monitoring the entire execution process, I put the & after it (but not after $hpm_ws_client.sh) and it seems to now be working properly.

Comment: You don't mention what `hpm_ws_client.sh` or `check_process_status.sh` is or does, so it's hard for me to say. Depending on how they work, you can background one, both in parallel or both in serial.

Comment: hpm_ws_client.sh kicks off a business model that matches the input parameters (which is what is being fed in from the .txt). Check_process_status.sh actually monitors the execution, and since we dont want to start the 3rd and 4th models until the first 2 have completed executing, I believe watching the status should suffice. That being said, I am totally open to any suggestions as the automation scripting is rather new to me.

Comment: If `hpm_ws_client.sh` just starts something and returns immediately while `check_process_status.sh` waits for it, it sounds like you'd want to just background `check_process_status.sh`

Comment: @thatotherguy I am working on the same script, and have a situation where I need the process we described to run, but immediately after the first two lines are completed in paralell, I need to kick off another execution that depends on its completion. Any ideas??